# Fabric.js paths not visible after loading JSON

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

My app works with a very old version of fabric.js, but I am trying to make it work with fabric 1.4

I want to draw on the canvas using the freedraw functionality, serialize the canvas, and then unserialize and load the canvas from JSON.

When I load the serialized data, using canvas.loadFromJSON(//myJson); , the path does not appear on the canvas. However, when I click on the canvas, the paths become visible. The paths disappear whenever the JSON is loaded again. (This is using the paths created from the canvas freedrawing).

However, when I load the circle and rectangle from the fabric.js tutorial, the objects are immediately visible when loaded (like I want them to be). I don't understand why these objects work when loaded, but the freedrawing data does not.

Here is a live version of the problem. The data loads every 7 seconds. Click on the canvas to make the path visible. http://drawfabric.meteor.com/

Here is my git repository for this problem 
https://github.com/mattlam/drawFabric/blob/master/client/freedraw-fabric.coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `canvas.renderAll()` or `canvas.renderTop()` after the `loadFromJSON` to update the canvas.

The `renderAll`/`renderTop` are called when you click on the canvas.